# Question about ortogonality on $L^2(\Omega)$

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $u\in L^2(\Omega)$.

Is the following proposition true?

$\big(\forall v\in H^1_0(\Omega)\big)\quad (u,v)_{0,\Omega}:=\displaystyle\int_\Omega uv=0$
then
$u=0$ ?

where $H_0^1(\Omega)$ are the element of the Hilbert $H^1(\Omega)$ with null trace on $\partial\Omega$.

Comment: hint - your question is equivalent to asking "is $H^1_0$ dense in $L^2$". What other dense subsets of $L^2$ do you know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $ C^\infty_c(\Omega)\subset H^1_0(\Omega)$ 
and $ C^\infty_c(\Omega) $ is dense in $L^2(\Omega)$.